# Scanner - Whitespace (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I would like to take several inputs from a user.

Input 1: *1*; Input 2: *2*; Input 3: *3*; Input n: *n*

However, if the user inputs 2 numbers, the scanner reads it too!

Input 1: *1_2* 2 is read.

How do I prevent the user from storing the nth value by entering white space?

Comment: If user enter `1 2` what do u want to do with ` 2` ?

Comment: I want to discard it. Basically, I get 1. Then I force the user to enter 2 in another scan.next()

Comment: Show your code. You should be using `nextInt()`, not `next()`. Unclear why you would want to discard anything. Or why you consider using whitespace to be 'circumventing the system'.

Comment: Using nextInt would throw an exception.  It's better to grab the line and then use a Pattern to extract the number string (which can then be turned into an int or Integer if you want).

Comment: @DanO Why would using `nextInt()` throw an exception?

Comment: Check my answer , I have used substring to find until first space

Comment: Try sending a82343 to scanner.nextInt and see what it does.  You get:

    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)

Comment: @DanO `a82343` has nothing whatsoever to do with the question. It's about entering *numbers.*

Comment: No... the OP explicitly states that he wants to ignore invalid characters.  The a is an invalid character.  The OP also states that he wants to grab the first valid number.  nextInt fails to do this if there is a non-digit present.

Comment: The person is asking with whitespace. A user wont enter a `a` in a number except in exceptional cases

Comment: @DanO The OP hasn't 'explicity stated' any such thing. His question is 'how do I prevent the user from circumventing the system by entering white space?'.

Comment: You are forgetting the first two lines of the OP.  He says "obedient user".  An a is a disobedient user.  A space is a disobedient user.  I'm giving the truly proper solution -- it's a whitelist.  You're trying to blacklist, which is bad practice.

Comment: @DanO You're commenting on (and answering) a different question, of your own invention. I don't know what your final sentence means, or what the objection to an exception on invalid input might be. OP has specifically disagreed with you.

Comment: Note: `My question is, how do I prevent the user from circumventing the system by entering white space?` whitespace.

Comment: @EJP Where does the OP specifically disagree with me?  Mine wasn't of my own invention -- the OP complains that a disobedient user can "circumvent".  I provide a complete means of preventing that.

Comment: @DanO What part of "how do I prevent the user from circumventing the system by entering white space?" don't you understand? and how many times does it have to be pointed out to you?

Comment: At no point is that someone specifically disagreeing.  Now, if the OP comes out and says, "I don't care if they give me something other than a digit or whitespace, I'm willing to have my application crash", then I'll agree with you.  It starts off saying explicitly, however, that the intention is to prevent 'disobedience' -- which was identified as inputting a non-digit.

Comment: Use hasNextInt() before directly calling nextInt().WhiteSpace is the default delimiter for Scanner.Do you also press the enter key after entering "3 4" if yes then it will create 2 tokens 3,4\n or 4\r

Comment: @EJP In fact, he says, "I want to discard it. Basically, I get 1. Then I force the user to enter 2 in another scan.next()".  Your method would fail to do this.  nextInt() with the input "12 123 1234 234" queues up the second digit (123).  So, before you get rude again, perhaps you should see where he *explicitly* rejected what you had.

Comment: He *cannot* use nextInt.  nextInt will not throw away the second number.  If I do "12 123 1234 234", nextInt gives 12.  If I do nextInt again I get 123.  Again gives 1234.  Again gives 234.  The user doesn't want this.  nextLine and a Pattern gives what the user asked for.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer; if you need negative numbers, just change that Pattern to "[\\-\\=]?\\d+" and you'll have those covered, too.  Happy programming!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a regular expression or pattern to grab the digits from the line.  If you want to throw an exception:

```
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
                String s = scanner.nextLine(pattern);
                System.out.println(s);
```

If you don't...

```
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
                String s = scanner.nextLine();
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.println(s.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
                } else {
                    // TODO The user didn't give us a number...
                }
```

Comment: Note that you would really want to make that pattern a private static final variable at the class level... I didn't have any of your code to put that into...

Comment: So... before downvoting... did the voter *try* the method?  I offered two perfect mechanisms, both of which really are the best means (far better than nextInt or trying to do a parseInt, which will fail with invalid input... mine lets you *find* the valid input and scream if there is no valid input).

Answer (score -1):

You can use BufferedReader or use `sc.nextLine()` and convert into integer.
If you want to discard second one,

```
String v = sc.nextLine() + " ";
int i = Integer.parseInt(v.substring(0,v.indexOf(" "));
```

Comment: You should at least trim first.  "     23423  234234"  Would cause a problem because of the first few spaces.

Comment: @DanO i dont get it why are u going offtrack ?  Its better to answer what user is asking

Comment: I'm not off-track, which is probably why mine was accepted as the answer.  You did v.indexOf(" ");  If there is even one leading space, that call returns 0.  By returning 0, your v.substring call is really v.substring(0,0).  Let's say that you decided to do the lastIndexOf -- that would fail if there were multiple trailing spaces.  It was for this reason that I said you at least need to trim the input.  The user would also have to be accepting either a crash (if an invalid int were parsed) or incur the cost of try-catch.  It's less secure, anyway, to use try-catch to validate.